# Is there any way for a PWA to suppress NFC?

Tags: android, ios, progressive-web-apps, nfc, qr-code

I'm adding a QR code to my (Vue-based) PWA, which will be read by a scanner in close proximity to an NFC reader (think like you might see on public transport). The trouble I'm having is that if NFC payment is enabled, when the phone is placed near to the scanner, it's also close enough to the NFC reader, which brings the payment app to the foreground, and so the QR code is hidden and can't be scanned.

I know that native Android/Apple apps have the ability to suppress the NFC reader on QR code screens specifically to prevent this issue, but is there a similar ability to do that from a PWA? This functionality is kind of ruined if not.

I've tried searching around this problem and found some potential Apple-specific ability (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpasslibrary/1617078-requestautomaticpasspresentation) but I'm not sure if that's available on PWA or just advice for iOS apps.

Other than that, all the advice I could find was about enabling NFC for a PWA, which is the exact opposite of what I need.

Comment: Apple Pay suppression is only available for native apps via a special entitlement from Apple. I am surprised you need to get so close to the QR code that it is triggering Apple Pay; you would typically scan a QR code from 6 inches away or more

Comment: @Paulw11 that was my worry, thanks. The QR code reader points towards the NFC reader, so the 6 inches places it perfectly on top of the NFC reader.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that the phone was reading the QR code.  I understand now.